# Could not load file or asembly 'MySqlConnector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d33d3e53aa5f8c92'. The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, nuget

I've been stock with that issue since few days. I use Visual Studio 2019 and made a project of type "Class Library (.NET Core)" with .NET 3.1. I need to use MySqlConnector (Or MySql.Data, it's the same issue with it) and it asks me to use the MySqlConnector version 1.0.0 which is what I use in the project.

Just to make it clear, I have the exact same issue with MySql.Data, so all the steps I made with MySqlConnector have been made with MySql.Data.

This is what I tried

1. First I looked if the versions fits, they do. The PublicKeyToken is also the same and the culture too.
2. I used DotPeek to look if the MySqlConnector.dll was included in the build and also looked the version / PublicKeyToken / Culture, all fits for what the program requests.
3. I used Assembly.LoadFile(); to directly load the MySqlConnector.dll (it's the first operation that the project does when its loaded) and dropped the dll file in the server.
4. I used a bindingRedirect in an App.config to be sure that the "newVersion" is 1.0.0 or 8.0.21 for MySql.Data.
5. I reloaded the project, unistalled MySql.Data & MySqlConnector and reinstalled them.
6. I tried to only use MySql.Data and then only MySqlConnector for possible library issues.
7. I made a complete new project and only used MySqlConnector nuget package to see if it was working, same error happens.

So yeah, I don't know what else I can do. Thanks for the help.

Edit: I also tried to compile the solution in JetBrain Rider, without any success.

Here is a piece of the code

```c
using MySqlConnector;

namespace PigraidCore
{
    [Plugin(PluginName = "plugin", Description = "description", PluginVersion = "Alpha-0.0.1", Author = "author")]
    public class PigraidCore : Plugin
    {
        //General
        private API provider;

        protected override void OnEnable()
            EventsHandler events = new EventsHandler();
            this.provider = new API();
            string ip = "ip";
            string database = "database";
            string uid = "user";
            string password = "password";
            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + ip + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
                return;
            }
```

Comment: It seems that you have used `app.config` file. Did you add a new config file manually into the net core lib project?

Comment: use this on app.config:`<configuration><runtime> <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="MySqlConnector"  
  publicKeyToken="d33d3e53aa5f8c92" culture="neutral" />  
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9"  newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>  
</dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding></runtime></configuration> `

Comment: Also, you can share a small sample or some key code with us to make your issue more clear:)

Comment: Here, I did an edit that shows a piece of the code. I tried with your config and it doesn't work

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT yes I added the config file manually, there weren't any when I made the project

Answer (score 0):

It is quite strange and I think your vs environment has something wrong. So please try the following suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`

**2)** disable any installed third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

**3)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all vs settings**

**4)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of your project.

**5)** delete all temp files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\AppData\Local\Temp`

and `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v*.*.****\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`

Remember to delte all temporary files under all `v*.*.***` folders

**6)** use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start a initial,default VS to test whether the issue persists.

**7)** [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it if there is a new release version.

Comment: Hi, I did all the steps and even completely unistalled Visual Studio and installed it back. It still does the same error.

Comment: I will try on my laptop so the environement is completely different

Comment: Ok so I installed Visual Studio 2019 on my laptop (that I actually never really use) and it still doesn't work

Comment: Quite strange. Not sure it is an issue between your nuget package and your project itself. Try to update `MySqlConnector` nuget package to the latest version `1.2.0`. Besides, what your provided is not enough. And you can try to upload a sample with github.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply, I made a github repository, there is the MiNET software, a sample plugin using MySqlConnector 1.0.0 (The software requests 1.0.0) & a sample using MySql.Data 1.2.0 (latest version) : https://github.com/CupidonSauce173/SamplePluginMiNET

Comment: The error said that the Absolute path information is required under `C:\projects\minet\src\MiNET\MiNET\Plugins\PluginManager.cs:line 221` and  `C:\projects\minet\src\MiNET\MiNET\Plugins\Plugin.cs:line 40` and `C:\projects\minet\src\MiNET\MiNET\Plugins\PluginManager.cs:line 622`. Since I cannot get the code under the MiNET plugin project, so I suggest you could check them carefully. And the issue is not related to the two sample projects.

Comment: The issue is with MiNET itself?

Comment: I suggest you should check the MiNET Plugins project carefully.

Comment: You mean the MiNET.Plugins or the sample plugins?

Comment: Actually, MiNET.Plugins